# Reusing httplib.HTTPConnection in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently inherited a python project, and I'm working on maintaining it now.  Part of the code makes a few hundred thousand requests from a website and saves the results to a database.  The code is reusing the same httplib.HTTPConnection object for reach request and then just looping over a

```
conn.request("GET",someString,'',headers)

response = conn.getresponse()
```

section.  A few days ago in my logs I saw that one of the requests threw the exception:

```
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

followed by every other conn.request() failing.  My first inclination was to just build a new connection for each request, but the perfomance impact of that was profound and horrible.  So my question is, how do I fix this, especially since I'm not 100% sure how I can even really test this.

If I just call conn.connect() after an exception, will it correctly reconnect?

I'm looking for advise on how to fix it and possibly how I could test it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you first need to decide the failure mode you want to handle. For instance, did the connection reset because of a temporary resource problem on the server and a quick turnaround connect will fix it? Or, is the server down or rebooting and you should abort your process?

Presuming the first case, I think you are thinking along the right lines. Try something like this (note, this is not working code - it's just an example of the logic):

```
while True:
    try:
        conn.request("GET",someString,'',headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
    except httplib.HTTPException, e:
        conn.connect()
        continue
    break
```

You should probably add some logic to that to pause between repeated connect attempts and to give up after a certain number of tries (which is basically the second scenario above).

In order to test this, try using tcpkill to cause the TCP connection to reset:

http://www.gnutoolbox.com/tcpkill-command/

Comment: This is the best way to do it, given httplib. However, it might be easier for OP to switch to a more powerful library like urllib3 or requests (requests is a wrapper around urllib3). urllib3 handles the connection pooling and re-using of connections, and initiates a new connection when one dies. It does all this automatically. httplib is considered archaic.

Comment: TCPkill is great, thank you for showing me that.  And I will take a look at swapping to urllib3 as Anorov suggests as well.  Thank you both.